# How to pick only one row from rows with common date in datetimefield?

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset

I am writing a django application where I have to pick only one row from and exclude the rest of them from multiple rows containing same date in their datetimefield column.

My model is:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to select only one user from each single date. Here is how i select all rows:

```
data = Model.objects.all()
```

How do I select only one user from each date in datetimefield?

Comment: `Model.objects.all().distinct('user_id')`

Comment: yes, but i have to get distinct dates from a datetimefield ignoring the time. Wonder how that goes?

Comment: Also i am using sqlite where distinct doesn't work. Any idea how to do that in sqlite?

Comment: Filter a date's interval (lower = time at 00:00:00; upper = time at 23:59:59) `Model.objects.all().filter(datetime__gte = startTimeAtDay).filter(datetime__lte = endTimeAtDay)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
data = Model.objects.all()

date_list = list(set([element.datetime.date() for element in data])) 

for date in date_list:  
obj = Model.objects.filter(datetime__date=date).first()
if isinstance(obj, Model): 
    user_list.append(obj.user_id)

return user_list
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want select one user per each datetime you may use this

```
data = Model.objects.all().distinct('datetime')
```

If you want select one user per each date you may use this

```
data = Model.objects.all().extra({'date': 'date(datetime)'}).distinct('date')
```

> `date` - is a SQL function may depend of sql server that you use

or you may use [TruncDate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.datetime.TruncDate) if you use django 1.10+

```
data = Model.objects.all().annotate(date=TruncDay('datetime').distinct('date')
```

Without `distinct` you may use this hack:

```
data = Model.objects.all().extra({'date': 'date(datetime)'}).values("data").annotate(Max("user_id"))
```